# Why can't I access objective-c methods even though file is in bridge?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have a project with a lot of `objective-c` code. Now I would like to access that code in my swift files. But for some reason I can't access the `objective-c` methods even though I can initiate an object of that class.

I have a `bridge-file` with all the `.h` files added called `projectName-Bridge-Header.h`

```
#import "NumberVerificationViewController.h"
```

And it's path is added in the `build-settings` (a side question: I can initiate an object from a class even though the bridge path isn't added to the `build-settings`. Why is that?):

[image]

I can initialize an object from the class, but I can't access the method:

```
var num = NumberVerificationViewController()
num.numberVerificationCallCompleted
```

The last line gives error that method does not exist.

I'm new to `objective-c` so it might be something really simple. Still, it's beyond me.

Comment: Please post code, not screenshots, and the complete error messages.

Comment: Is numberVerificationCallCompleted exposed in .h file

Comment: At least in the .h file , you must add the method signature to make it public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, it looks like you might be missing the declaration in the .h file to make the method public.

```
NumberVerificationViewController.h
-(void)numberVerificationCallCompleted:(NSNumber*)responseNumber;

NumberVerificationViewController.m
-(void)numberVerificationCallCompleted:(NSNumber*)responseNumber {
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes, of course! Thanks, completely forgot about checking that. I blame being new to objective-c lol. Thanks again for taking the time! :)

Comment: As for the side question: any idea why I don't need to add bridge location to build settings. It works fine without doing it, but every tutorial I come across say I have to add it.